# How to record a stream into a file while using appsink using GStreamer

Tags: stream, gstreamer, tee

I am using the following command to receive "frame event" in my C++ code and from GStreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vv udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! videoconvert ! appsink name=sink
```

And it works fine.

Now I am trying to add a recording using [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)).
I tried:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vv udpsrc port=5000 ! tee name=t t. ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink ! t. ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

for example, but I get this error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: syntax error
```

I don't get how to use the tee.
Each part works fine alone, but when I am using the tee it doesn't work.

What is the correct syntax?

(In my code, instead of using *gstlaunch-1.0.exe*, I am using gst_parse_launch.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pipe there is a `!` between `appsink` and `t` (tee) elements. This connects the them. You want the branches to be separate.

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -vv udpsrc port=5000 ! tee name=t t. ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink   t. ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

*A small note:* Adding caps before tee would be more practical, so that you wouldn't need to write it twice.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vv udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink  t. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

Comment: thanks. I don't get the error "WARNING: erroneous pipeline: syntax error". I am doing some test with the camera soon.

Comment: it saves the results in a file when using with gst-launch-1.0. 
but when using with c++ the file stays at 0kb. and the appsink doesn't get the frame anymore. is there a way to check what understand gst_parse_launch.

Comment: after gst_parse_launch, I do `GstElement *sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(m_pipeline), "sink");    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals((GstAppSink*)sink, true);
gst_app_sink_set_drop((GstAppSink*)sink, true);`

Comment: it's solved. I need to add "queue" in the appsink tee. don't know why.
`udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! videoconvert ! appsink name=sink  t. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=Flight.mp4 name=record`
and add an eos_event manually